# serve images from protected folder using Oauth2, angular and yii2 REST

Tags: angularjs, rest, angularjs-directive, oauth-2.0, yii2

I have project that have to deal with very sensitive images, which shouldn't be accessable for unauthorised users, saved on protected location. I've done this before, for regular http requests, but now I have angular app on frontend with Oauth2 client, and Yii2 powered API on server side. I am wondering what is best practice to do this, should I create new yii\web\Controller to serve image (creating and deleting images would still be in rest controller), which should bring me some difficulties with authorisation, and it looks kind a hacky.
Or should I use raw output format in yii REST controller, and render image as response?
I would prefer second approach if it is feasable, because I'm new with angular.js, and not sure how to do this, and idealy I would like to render images simple as

```
<img src="example/image/123" />
```

I would like to exclude base64 encoding, since that would take some processing power on both sides

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second approach is possible via [`URL.createObjectURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL). On the PHP side, you would just use something like [`readfile()`](http://php.net/manual/function.readfile.php). On the Angular side, try something like this

```
$http.get('example/image/123', {
    responseType: 'blob',
    headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer super-secret-token'
    },
    transformResponse: function(data) {
        return ($window.URL || $window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(data);
    }
}).then(function(response) {
    $scope.imageUri = response.data;
});
```

and in your template

```
<img ng-src="{{imageUri}}">
```

---

You should probably also fire [`URL.revokeObjectURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/revokeObjectURL) when you no longer need the image such as when your current scope is destroyed, eg

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    ($window.URL || $window.webkitURL).revokeObjectURL($scope.imageUri);
});
```

Comment: Just addition. Better use `x-send-file` headers for apache with mod enabled or nginx. Because `readfile()` will hit performance badly for high loads.

Comment: @Phil, I would rather bind response data directly to ``src`` attribute with ``element.attr('src', response.data)`` so there is no need to contain and revoke data from ``$scope`` object. Thanks

Comment: @dzona sure, you can do that. Using `$scope` was just an example